# Android Studio is giving error when I use webview. The error is as follows inconvertible types cannot convert int to webview

Tags: android

The error occurred when I used Webview to create a webpage app. The error is "Cannot cast int to android webpage view".
I look forward to it solution
Thank you! in advance

[image]

Comment: Don't paste error messages or code as images. Put it in your question. You're wasting bandwidth for everyone

Comment: @NickCardoso he can't do that as he doesn't have enough reputation!

Comment: He can't write text @PareshMayani? I dont think you know what you're talking about.

Comment: you are just missing Java basics. Go through some Java tutorial before you continue.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a findViewById() call

Correct syntax is:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Now in detail, you are trying to cast R.id.webview which actually return int ID value of the view that you have taken in XML layout and then you are trying to cast that directly into the Webview by writing a statement:

```
webView = (WebView) (R.id.webview)
```

And there it's showing incovertible types because you are trying to cast integer ID value into WebView. In Android, when you want to find views from XML then need to use `findViewById()` method.

Comment: @KapilRajput hahaha that happens!

Comment: Oh that is a horrendous error. Sorry to waste everybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

use `webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);`